# can Nativescript run at browser?

Tags: ionic-framework, nativescript

I was working with Ionic but decided to move to Nativescript for not webView , but is there any way to work with browser as the ionic do (ionic serve ) for developing its much faster without running on android or emulator.Also, I heard some news that ionic tries to move that webView to phones engine as nativescript does, is that true ?

Answer (score 3):

No, unfortunately there's no way right now to run Nativescript code at a browser. And Ionic doesn't generate native elements, if this is what you are asking!

Comment: Thank you for your  quick reply, I'm still not sure for changing the framework do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: I would try React Native, they have a bigger community and I have been hearing good things about it. I tried Nativescript and liked it, but had to build a lot of stuff myself that MAYBE wouldn't need to with React Native, as there are a lot more public plugins for React Native - this is, if you really want to change to a framework that generate native apps, sometimes Ionic is just fine!